# SOS! New Developer Facing White Screen of Death on WordPress Install (Comprehensive Details)

Tags: local-installation

I'm a new developer recently thrown into the world of WordPress and tasked with setting it up independently. I'm encountering the dreaded White Screen of Death (WSOD) during installation.

- Followed this guide for installation:
  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress The
  first installation worked perfectly. However, when I attempted to set
  up a second WordPress instance, things didn't work so well.Then I I
  uninstalled Apache, deleted the virtual host file, the entire Apache
  folder, and the document root folder for the first WordPress.
- On a fresh install attempt:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 results in WSOD instead of the WordPress language selection screen.
  ```

  Tried troubleshooting using this guide:
  https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/

Steps Attempted:

```
    Increased memory limit.
    Added debug code (`define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`) to wp-config.php.

Unfortunately:
    No debug log file was created in the wp-content directory.
    Browser Network Tab:
        127.0.0.1 returns a 304 (Not Modified) status code.
    Tried accessing localhost in a different browser after resetting it: I get some php code formatted wll.
```

Additional Observations:

```
Accessing 127.0.0.1/wp-login.php or 127.0.0.1/wp-config.php displays plain text PHP with words like eror.
I tried in another browser resetting the browser to default settings and then on localhost I get

<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Request for Help:

Help me out. I am at my wits end.

Comment: a white screen of death means a PHP fatal error occurred and instead of printing it to the screen it went to the PHP error log. Look in your PHP error log and you'll find the actual problem. It's likely though that your server is not configured correctly, especially if you're seeing PHP code in the browser, these sort of problems aren't WordPress problems though, they're deeper Nginx/Apache level problems that would break _all_ PHP applications not just WordPress. Without the PHP error message though you won't be able to find much help online.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks. The issue was php was not enabled in apache server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Tom has said, this is most probably "server" issue, not a WordPress one.

You should check your error_log file to see if it gives you any insights. It should be in the same folder/directory in which the WordPress installation is.

If you don't see anything there, you may try to force the WordPress installation to show you the errors in the browser. You can do so from the wp-config.php, configuring the boolean WP_DEBUG to true.

But if you are seeing the content of the index.php file as you are telling us, the most probable cause is that PHP isn't working as it should, since it isn't interpreting .php files but showing it's contents instead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. PHP was not enabled in my apache server. Thanks